# Save association Grape API Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-grape, grape-api

Just want to how can i save a model with validation in Grape Gem?
`User has_one profile`

The required fields are name, username, password and address.
and also what if there are validation in profile Model if the user is save first? any suggestion to make my code better?
here's the sample code i made.

```
desc "User registration"
            params do
                requires :name, type: String #profile
                requires :address, type: String #profile
                requires :primary_contact_number, type: String #profile
                requires :other_number, type: String #profile
                requires :description, type: String #profile
                requires :username, type: String #user
                requires :password, type: String #user
            end
            post :register do
                # Save user?
                user = User.create!({
                })
                Profile.create({
                   user: user.id
                })

            end
```

Comment: Grape doesn't validate models, it only really interacts with them indirectly (via Grape::Entity and `present`/`expose`) for return values. Could you explain which data library you are using?

Comment: I integrated grape with rails right now. so it's using ActiveRecord validation. But aside from validation i want to save some associate in create User to Profile where in if there's an invalid field in profile the user will also not be saved.

Comment: It all has to be done using ActiveRecord features and methods, and has very little if anything to do with Grape. So you may get a quicker/better response if you change title and tags to put more emphasis on the need for help with ActiveRecord (still mention Grape, because it *might* be relevant, but it isn't the main topic of the question). I say this because I do know Grape quite well, and clicked on the question to see if I could help. I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to user model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

Then you can modify the grape to be:

```
params do
  requires :username, type: String #user
  requires :password, type: String #user

  optional :profile, type: Hash do
    requires :name, type: String #profile
    requires :address, type: String #profile
    requires :primary_contact_number, type: String #profile
    requires :other_number, type: String #profile
    requires :description, type: String #profile
  end
end

post :register do
  user = User.new params[:user]
  if user.save
    present user, with: API::Entities::User
  else
    # TODO: raise an error
  end
end
```

The user will be validated only if the profile is valid.